# how to change offset in SVG for mobile phone authentication animation

Tags: svg

Here is the code where Im creating the svg paths for different animation, but the offset is not changing via JS code.

The offset is changing via HTML but not vis Jquery.

```css
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Ripple Effect Animation</title>
<style>

.container {
align-items: center;
display: flex;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center; 
background: white;
margin: 0;
  }
  .circles {
  height: 90vmin;
  position: relative;
  width: 90vmin;
  
  > div {
animation: growAndFade 2s infinite ease-out;
background-color: dodgerblue;
border-radius: 150px;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 110px;
  }
  
  .circle1 {
animation-delay: 0s;    
  }
  .circle2 {
animation-delay: 0.5s; 
  }
  .circle3 {
animation-delay: 1s;
  }
}

.phone {
position: absolute;
width: 100px; 
height: 220px; 
border: 10px solid #000;
border-radius: 20px;
background: white;
z-index: 2;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .notch {
width: 60px; 
height: 15px;
background: #000;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #000; 
border-radius: 15px;
top: -10px;
left: 20px;
  }
/* Face - Start */  
  .faceRect {
width: 70px; 
height: 70px;
position: relative;
border: 8px solid #D3D3D3; 
border-radius: 15px;
top: 80px;
left: -14px;
  }
  
  .whiteBar1 {
width: 40px; 
height: 10px;
background: white;
position: relative;
top: -10px;
left: 15px;
  }
  
  .whiteBar2 {
width: 40px; 
height: 10px;
background: white;
position: relative;
top: 80px;
left: 0px;
  }
  
  .whiteBar3 {
width: 10px; 
height: 40px;
background: white;
position: relative;
top: -53px;
left: -25px;
  }
  
  .whiteBar4 {
width: 10px; 
height: 40px;
background: white;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 80px;
  }
  
  .eyeL {
width: 12px; 
height: 12px;
background: #D3D3D3;
position: relative;
border-radius: 6px;
top: 3px;
left: -56px;
animation: eyeAnimate 2s infinite;
  }
  
  .eyeR {
width: 12px; 
height: 12px;
background: #D3D3D3;
position: relative;
border-radius: 6px;
top: 0px;
left: 30px;
animation: eyeAnimate 2s infinite;
  }
  
  .mouth {
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
left: -60px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border: 5px solid;
border-bottom-left-radius: 40px 40px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 40px 40px;
border-color: transparent transparent #D3D3D3 transparent;
  }
  
  .scannerShadow {
width: 62px; 
height: 67px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #94ffff);
position: fixed;
opacity: 0.8;
position: absolute;
top: -16px;
left: -65px;
animation: scanningShadow 2s infinite;
  }
  .scannerBar {
width: 62px; 
height: 10px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
opacity: 1;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 999;
animation: scanning 2s infinite;
  }
  
  .check { 
height: 50px; 
width: 25px;
opacity: 0;
border-bottom: 10px solid white; 
border-right: 10px solid white; 
position: absolute;
top: -20px;
left: 10px;
animation: flikker 2s infinite ease-out;
  }
  
  .resultCircle {
animation: flikker 2s infinite ease-out;
background-color: red;
border-radius: 150px;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left: -75px;
top: -85px;
  }
  
  .x-symbol {
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
left: -10px;
top: -15px;
opacity: 0;
  }

  .x-line {
position: absolute;
width: 5px;
height: 100%;
background-color: white; /* Adjust color as needed */

  }

  .x-line:nth-child(1) {
animation: flikkerXL 2s infinite ease-out;
transform: rotate(45deg);
left: calc(50% - 1.5px);
  }

  .x-line:nth-child(2) {
animation: flikkerXR 2s infinite ease-out;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
right: calc(50% - 1.5px);
  }
  /* Face - END */
  
/* Animation */

@keyframes growAndFade {
  0% {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes flikkerXR {
  0% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  25% {
transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  50% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  75% {
transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes flikkerXL {
  0% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(45deg);
  }
  25% {
transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(45deg);
  }
  75% {
transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flikker {
  0% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(45deg);
  }
  25% {
transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(45deg);
  }
  75% {
transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
transform: scale(0.8) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes 1eyeAnimate {
  0% {
transform: translateY(0px) scaleY(1);
  }
  50% {
transform: translateY(-2px) scaleY(0.1);
  }
  100% {
transform: translateY(0px) scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scanning {
  0% {
transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
transform: translateY(55px);
  }
  100% {
transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes scanningShadow {
  0% {
transform: translateY(0px) scaleY(1);
  }
  50% {
transform: translateY(-25px) scaleY(0.1);
  }
  100% {
transform: translateY(0px) scaleY(1);
  }
}

/* Animation */

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle1"></div>
  <div class="circle2"></div>
  <div class="circle3"></div>
</div>
<div class="phone">
    <div class="notch"/>
    <div class="faceRect"/>
    <div class="whiteBar1"/>
    <div class="whiteBar2"/>
    <div class="whiteBar3"/>
    <div class="whiteBar4"/>
    <div class="mouth"/>
</div>    
<div>
    <div class="scannerShadow"/>
    <!--<div class="scannerBar"/>-->
</div>
<div>       
    <div class="eyeL"/>
    <div class="eyeR"/>
</div>
<div class="resultCircle"></div>
<div class="check"></div>
<div class="x-symbol">
  <div class="x-line"></div>
  <div class="x-line"></div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the JS code?